# Move schema_version during migration

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I have a schema `foo` that, among other tables, contain `schema_version` and now I want to rename `foo` to `bar` as part of a migration like so `ALTER SCHEMA foo RENAME TO bar`. This migration currently fails since after the operation flyway is no longer able to find and update `foo.schema_version` as it is now located under `bar.schema_version` which is the desired outcome.

Is there a way to move schema_version as part of a migration?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?